# Showing surjectivity in $(G\times H)/G^*\cong H$ where $G^*=(a,e)$

Tags: group-theory

The following exercise is from Hungerford's Abstract Algebra an Introduction 3rd edition.  Chapter 8 section 3.

Let $G$ and $H$ be groups and let $G^*$ be the subset of $G\times H$ consisting of all $(a,e)$ with $a\in G$.

(a) Show that $G^*$ is isomorphic to $G$.
(b) Show that $G^*$ is normal subgroup of $G\times H$
(c) Show that $(G\times H)/G^*\cong H.$

I have two related questions about part (c).  (1) can I define the isomorphic mapping $f:(G\times H)/G^* \rightarrow H$ as $f(G^*(g,h))=h$ instead of the reverse $k:H \rightarrow (G\times H)/G^*$ as $k(h)=(G^*(g,h))$ with $G^*=(a,e)$.

The reason I asked about this is because I don't understand how the book show surjectivity of $k$.  If I let $f(G^*(g,h))=h$, then for any $h\in H$, a $(g,h)\in G\times H$ so that $f(G^*(g,h))=f(ag,h)=h$ for any $a, g\in G$, since $f$ by definition is a projection function that collapses it's first variable.

The book's solution for showing surjectivity is as follows:

> For any $(g,h)\in G\times H$, we have $k(h)=G^*(e,h)=G^*(g,e)(e,h)=G^*(g,h)$.

How did $G^*(e,h)=G^*(g,h)$.  The $(g,e)$ disappeared for no apparent reasons.  If someone can tell me whether if I can show surjectivity by doing an opposite mapping and also what the book's solution is trying to do.  I really appreciate it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: @Shaun the book is Hungerford Abstract Algebra An introduction, 3rd edition.  The reason I am asking if I can use the opposite mapping because I did not understand what the book's solution.

Comment: @Shaun I have edited the question with the relevant information about the origin of the question.

Comment: Two cosets $G^*x$ and $G^*y$ are equal if and only if $xy^{-1}\in G^*$. Taking $x=(e,h)$ and $y=(g,h)$, is $xy^{-1}=(e,h)(g,h)^{-1}=(e,h)(g^{-1},h^{-1})$ in $G^*$? If so, then they are equal. Why does "$(g,e)$ disappear[]"? Because $G^*(g,e) = G^*$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin okay okay,.  I forgot the little detail about cosets you mentioned.  Thank you for clarifying that for me.

Comment: "Surjectivity of $K$"... $K$ is not mentioned. Did you mean $k$?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin yes i meant lower case $k$.  I will make the correction

Comment: "I forgot that little detail about cosets".... It's not a "little detail", it's a key fact about cosets that is key to the whole thing being well-defined!

Comment: @ArturoMagidin in which direction of these types of mapping do I have to show well definedness?

Comment: @SethMai When elements of your domain have multiple "names" and your definition depends on the  name of  the element, you must verify well-definedness. It's not a question of "direction". The elements of $H$ don't have multiple names. The elements of $G/G^*$ do.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin oh so if I have a function with domain involving equivalence relations like cosets or quotient vector spaces, etc.  I have to show well definedness.  But if they are in the range, then i don't have to worry doing that extra bit of writing.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin When I say i forgot the little fact about cosets.  I think the way you express it "$G^*x=G^*y$ iff $xy^{-1}\in G$.

Comment: @SethMai: And when I say this is a *key fact* I meant that it is a **key fact**, not a little fact.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I will definitely remember it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, the best way to prove that a quotient $G/N$ is isomorphic to a group $K$ is to define a surjective homomorphism $G\to K$ that has kernel $N$, and then invoke the First Isomorphism Theorem. So you would want to define a homomorphism $G\times H\to H$ that has kernel $G^*$...

You write "$G^*=(a,e)$". That's incorrect. The left hand side is a subgroup of $G\times H$; the right hand side is a *single element* of $G\times H$. That's at best misleading, and at worst betrays a fundamental categorical misunderstanding. Instead, you have
$$G^* = \{(a,e)\in G\times H\mid a\in G\}.$$

Your approach requires you to show that $f$ is **well-defined**: since cosets may have multiple representatives or "names", you must show that if $G^*(g,h) = G^*(a,b)$, then $h$ (that is,  the value you give to $f(G^*(g,h))$) is equal to $b$ (the value you give to $f(G^*(a,b))$). The likely reason that Hungerford is defining the map in the other direction is that such a check is not required; but you have not included it, so your argument is at best incomplete.

In general, for any subgroup $B$ of a group $A$, and any elements $b\in B$ and $a\in A$, you have $Ba = Bba$. Since $(g,e)\in G^*$, it follows that $G^*(e,h) = G^*(g,e)(e,h)= G^*(g,h)$.

Comment: the isomorphism theorems are being introduced in the next section.  So in the section I am in, I am not suppose to use those.  I never can remember which direction of mapping I should use if I can't use the isomorphism theorems.  I learned rings before groups.  I remember learning about the isomorphism theorems about rings, depending on which books I see those theorems, some authors does it one way, other authors does it the other direction.

Comment: @SethMai: Well, that explains why you aren't using it... The problem with trying to define a map with domain a quotient $G/N$ is that you must make sure that the map is well-defined, and that the value does not depend on the "name" of the coset. That's why you would want to define it in "the other direction", and why once you have the isomorphism theorems you want to define them from $G$ and not from $G/N$.